Blender UV bake looks different from nodes result
As the title said, I originally created the texture using nodes and when I UV unwrap it using bake it looks really different. Here's some image for details
Here's the node result:

The nodes:

And below is the bake result and settings:


Help really appreciated ! Thanks
